# As3 input-field number condition

Tags: actionscript-3, validation

I'm trying to validate a flash form. 
In one case I need to know how to check if the value is a number.

If someone could show me this if-sentence, i would be very grateful! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Number](http://www.adobe.com/livedocs/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/Number.html) to cast a String to a Number and then [isNaN](http://www.adobe.com/livedocs/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/package.html#isNaN()) to check if the result is a Number:

```
var str:String="1234";

var n:Number = Number(str);
if (isNaN(n)) {
 trace(str+" is not a number");
} else {
 trace(str+" is a number");
}

str="12a4";
n=Number(str);

if (isNaN(n)) {
 trace(str+" is not a number");
} else {
 trace(str+" is a number");
}
```